# Outlook Add-in displayReplyForm

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Add-in/Add-on for Outlook Mobile. I want to create a "Reply With" plugin so I'm doing: `Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm("Reply")`.

But I get the response that I don't have enough permissions, this is my how my permission looks like on the `manifest.xml`:
`<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>`
Should't this permission be enough to make the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displayReplyForm() API is not supported on mobile platforms (Android or iOS). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-messageread-displayreplyformasync-member(1)

If you need this support, you can raise a request for this. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) . Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.